# Can I stop flesh eating plants from spawning?

Tags: craft-the-world

In Craft the World, when you dig your mining tunnels, they always get clogged up with flesh eating plants after a while. Is there anything I can do to prevent them from spawning so my dwarves can go through the tunnel unhampered?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a light source that will light the area or remove the "back" wall on which they spawn. This goes for the non flesh eating plants and ghosts as well.